Не работают сессии в боте telegraf.js
Помогите разобраться с сессиями в телеграм-боте. Смотрел примеры кода, вопросы/ответы на этом сайте, не могу никак понять, уже запутался. Суть бота: записать человека на определенное время и дату.
Проверяю бота на двух пользователях, при работе одного пользователя, бот берет данные другого пользователя. Использую ctx.session для записи различных данных.
Код bot.js
bot.use(session())
bot.use(stage.middleware())
bot.start(async (ctx) => {
    if (ctx.message.text){     
        ctx.session.text = ctx.message.text        
        await ctx.scene.enter('number', async (ctx, next) => {return next()})    
    }         
})  

Код сцены, где путаются данные пользователей. okp1 - данные, которые ввел пользователь
curr.enter(async (ctx,next) => {
            okp1 = ctx.session.okp
            chatId = ctx.session.chatId
            kk=0 
            ctx.session.kk=kk
            kk = ctx.session.kk             

            year = for_user_date.Year_from_Date() 

            ctx.session.month = for_user_date.Month_from_Date()
            month = ctx.session.month 
            //вот это первоначально работает верно
            ctx.session.curr_mess_id = await ctx.reply(`Выберите дату. Запись на ${for_user_date.Month_from_Date_Word()} для ${okp1}`,cOptions,{chat_id:chatId});

            ctx.session.month = month
            ctx.session.kk = kk
            ctx.session.okp = okp1
            ctx.session.chatId = chatId      

            return next()

        })


currcalendar.on('callback_query', async (ctx, next) =>{
            ctx.session.okp = okp1
            ctx.session.chatId = chatId

            okp1 = ctx.session.okp
            chatId = ctx.session.chatId
            kk = ctx.session.kk
            ctx.session.inline_choose = await ctx.update.callback_query.data
            inline_choose = ctx.session.inline_choose
            
            if(inline_choose == 'next'){                                
                    //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ ПЕРЕПУТАЛИСЬ
                   //В плане у двух пользователей переменные chatId и okp1 стали одинаковые
                ctx.session.next_mess_id = await ctx.reply(`Выберите дату. Запись на ${for_user_next_month.Month_from_Date_Word()} для ${okp1}`, nOptions,{chat_id:chatId}); 
                ctx.session.kk = 1
                kk = ctx.session.kk       

                ctx.session.curr_mess_id = {message_id: undefined}
               
            }

           if(inline_choose == 'old'){                
                ctx.session.curr_mess_id = await ctx.reply(`Выберите дату. Запись на ${for_user_date.Month_from_Date_Word()} для ${okp1}`,cOptions,{chat_id:chatId}); 
                ctx.session.kk = 2
                kk = ctx.session.kk
                
                ctx.session.next_mess_id = {message_id: undefined}

            }

